# Running Bash Script Every Minute Between Two Times

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I need to run a bash script every minute between **06:00UTC** and **14:00UTC** in `crontab`.

Is this the best/most efficient way to do this?

```
0-59/1 6 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 7 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 8 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 9 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 10 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 11 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 12 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 13 * * * script.sh
0-59/1 14 * * * script.sh
```

Comment: Use `*` for `0-59/1`. The rest is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* 6-14 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```